# Write to a specific file every 10 secs

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-io, bufferedwriter, spring-scheduled

I am trying to use spring boot's @Scheduled to print current system time to a specific text file every 10 seconds.

I have managed to create something like below:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000) // 10 seconds
public void writeToMyFile() {
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\temp\\envVarFile.txt", true));
        SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        try {
            writer.append(formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        writer.close(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I don't know if I am creating a file new file or I am writing on the initially created "envVarFile" file.

I would be glad if someone could help.

**!Important!:**
The solution of @Rakesh works but when applied to the code under the circumstances of the envVarFile.txt being present under the directory of temp which is inside C:

Comment: Environment variables don't change. Why are you wanting to write repeatedly?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It doesn't need to be envişronment variables it can be any arbitrary text that is not my main concern here.

Comment: As per the question writing to a new file or existing file and answer provided below marked not useful. Please confirm the reason or explain the question more detail

Comment: @Rakesh I am currently trying your solution, I wasn't the person to mark the answer not useful.

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply. please try and let me know if you face any issues. We are using several places @Scheduled as we are having several batch jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below

```
  File yourfile = new File(filename);
        if(yourfile.exists()){
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }else{
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
        }
```